# Can't access object from collection

Tags: excel, vba, macos

Apologies for what is no doubt a simple question - am very new to coding so even finding the answer from existing information is tough.

Anyway...

I've defined a Class with 4 value (1 x Single, 1 x String (to use as key), and 2 x Range)

I've then managed to set the Collection based on the class and populate the collection, and can use Debug.Print to print the entire collection's values and also to count the number of items in the collection.

But I can't access a single object from the collection, either by using index position or the specified Key.

When trying I get

> Runtime error 438 - Object doesn't support this property or method.

The underlying spreadsheet is a 4 column, 200 row sheet, and the eventual goal is for each row to be an object, and then populate a given location for an object (row) with a variable defined in a separate set of code.

Anyway, the Class (PriceLadder) code is:

```
Public ladderPriceKey As String
Public ladderPrice As Single
Public layMatchedLocation As Range
Public backMatchedLocation As Range
```

and then the module code is:

```
Sub initialiseLadder()


'initialise ladder as collection

Dim ladder As Collection
Set ladder = New Collection

Dim cell As Range
Dim price As PriceLadder

'for each cell in Column A

For Each cell In Sheets(2).Range("A11:A220") ' & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)


        ' create a new priceladder object

        Set price = New PriceLadder

        ' fill the data
        price.ladderPrice = cell
        price.ladderPriceKey = cell
        Set price.layMatchedLocation = Range(cell.Offset(0, 2).Address(RowAbsolute:=True, ColumnAbsolute:=True))
        Set price.backMatchedLocation = Range(cell.Offset(0, 3).Address(RowAbsolute:=True, ColumnAbsolute:=True))

        ' add the price to the collection of ladder prices
        ladder.Add price, price.ladderPriceKey 'price.ladderPriceKey set as the key for the collection object

    Next


Debug.Print ladder.Count
Debug.Print ladder("10")

 '  Dim p As PriceLadder
'For Each p In ladder
'Debug.Print "PriceKey: " & p.ladderPriceKey & vbTab & "BackLocation: " & p.backMatchedLocation.Address & vbTab & "LayLocation: " & p.layMatchedLocation.Address & vbTab & "Price: " & p.ladderPrice()


'    Next
End Sub
```

The line that produces the error is:

```
Debug.Print ladder("10")
```

where "10" is one of the values added as a key from price.ladderKeyPrice

Really sorry if this is a horrible newbie type question.

Thanks for any help than can be given.

Richard

Comment: ladder(10), no quotation marks

Comment: Is 10 definitely there as a key?  is one of the `cell` values 10?

Comment: @peakpeak I think the op wants the key of 10, not item 10?

Comment: Apologies, I'd thought you could use Keys in a collection.  Is that not the case?  I'd thought collections could use Keys if they were unique strings, and dictionaries enabled use of integers.

As for is one of the values of price.ladderKeyPrice "10", yes it definitely is (the Immediate Window print out validates this for me if I print out the entire collection with the last 3 commented out lines at the bottom).

Thanks to all those trying to help this coding virgin!

Comment: @KostasK. nope. `Collection.Add` takes an optional second parameter named `Key`, which must be a `String`. That key can absolutely be used to retrieve collection items - *that's what it's for*. The advantage of a dictionary is that you can iterate the keys themselves, not that it's keyed. A collection can absolutely be keyed.

Comment: Also as another note, if I use 'ladder(10)" (so try and access the object that is in the index position 10) this also returns an error.

Comment: Have you tried using a key that doesn't *look like a number*? e.g. try prefixing it with a `"K"` or something. Also assign it explicitly to `cell.Value` or `cell.Text`, instead of relying on the implicit default member call.

Comment: Hi Mat...I've not tried either of those.  I'll try and work out how to do so and report back.

Comment: Also these unqualified `Range` calls are implicitly referring to `ActiveSheet`. If that's not `Sheets(2)` (`cell.Parent`), you're possibly running into a run-time error right there, or storing data from the wrong sheet.

Comment: Thanks - think maybe I'm trying to tackle this task too early?  Might head back to the books/videos!

Comment: @Mat's Mug Thanks for clarifying this Mat. I was under the impression items can only retrieved by index.